# Simplified Java one-liner validation and assignment and return

Tags: java, java-8, fluent

I want to simplify the following Java 8 block executed on method start:

```
public void handle(Context ctx) {
    String param = ctx.getParam(name);
    if (!Validation.validate(param)) {
        ctx.markError().end();
        return;
    }
    ... do the same with other params

    ... finally, busines logic on params
}
```

This is repeated for many params. I would like to be able to write this block more fluently, with less chars as possible, using Java 8 syntax. The problem here is that we have an assignment and method flow breaking (return).

I was looking for something like:

```
if (Validator.on(ctx).param("instanceId")) return;
```

however, we are missing an assignment here. I tried to used some `Consumer`, but `param` must be (effectively) `final`. Something like (in *sudo*):

```
if (Validator.on(ctx).param("instanceId").into(param)) return;
if (Validator.on(ctx).param("instanceId", value -> param = value) return;
```

(Note that `ctx.end()` is wrapped inside).

Of course, this is not working in Java. Any ideas?

NOTE: Im in control of the code, i.e. no 3rd party is used here.

EDIT: If computers could understand plain English, I would say:

> Validate parameter `name` of `context`; if it is valid, assign it to a `param`; if not, exit the method. Please :)

**EDIT2**: It does NOT need to be Java 8! I mean, it is allowed to use Java 8 trickeries, but it is NOT mandatory.

Comment: Are you building the API and you want it to be fluent? Or are you working with an existing one? And why is this not working?

Comment: I am building API - so I have all the power :)

Comment: If you're building it, we'd need to see what the rest of the method does. Why are you returning early? You could have an `Optional<String>` and handle it from there. I'm not sure a design question is on-topic here but we definitely need to see more code.

Comment: @Tunaki I edited question a bit - there is simply no more code needed, believe me. This is not a design question; just syntax one. I am looking for the cleanest syntax to avoid repeated code.

Comment: Does your `ctx.end()` call happen at the end of your business logic as well?

Comment: @MrWiggles yes, it does, however, `ctx` gets filled with more stuff. See my edit: `ctx.markError().end();`

Comment: Why not just move the validation to a private method or to some utility class' method? Then it would be easier to create a one-liner from that.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Validation itself is in the util method (here it is `validate`). However, the _usage_ of the util method is the problem here, that I want to optimize.

Comment: Why do you care how many lines or characters it took to write that? If it's working, it's working... don't over-complicate things :)

Comment: The first line works in Java. Check fluent interfaces, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#Java

Comment: @SnakeDoc I want to push languages to the max use:) And it is repeating pattern :)

Comment: Do you only ever use one parameter or more?

Comment: @MrWiggles more. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a helper function:

```
private static boolean check(Context ctx, String value)
{
  if (!Validation.validate(value)) {
    ctx.markError().end();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Usage would look like this:

```
String param = ctx.getParam(name);
if (!check(ctx, param)) return;
/* Assign and test other variables... */
/* Use variables... */
```

The helper function could be given more visibility and moved to another class, as appropriate.

The helper function could be parameterized with a `Predicate` to perform custom validation, and a `Runnable` to perform custom failure handling. (Or `Consumer`, accepting the value or context; or `BiConsumer`, accepting value *and* context.)

Comment: Actually, this is the closest to what I think it will be the outcome ;) Thanx

Answer (score 4):

The problem stem from overlooking that an early `return` is just a short-hand for a conditional, e.g. instead of

```
if (!Validation.validate(param)) {
    ctx.markError().end();
    return;
}
... business logic on param
```

you could also write

```
if (!Validation.validate(param)) {
    ctx.markError().end();
} else {
... business logic on param
}
```

So all your validation framework needs to support, is an action which should be performed in the *successful* case, specified either, as a `Consumer<String>` or a `BiConsumer<Context,String>`, depending on whether the context is required or not. Then, the use case might look like:

```
public void handle(Context ctx) {
    Validator.on(ctx).param("instanceId").ifValid( param -> {
        ... business logic on param
    });
}
```

or

```
public void handle(Context ctx) {
    Validator.on(ctx).param("instanceId").ifValid( (context,param) -> {
        ... business logic on param
    });
}
```

if the context is required. In principle, the action could access `ctx` if the context is required but you may want to support a use case like:

```
public void handle(Context ctx) {
    Validator.on(ctx).param("instanceId").ifValid(this::handleValidated);
}
private void handleValidated(Context ctx, String param) {
    ... business logic on param
}
```

which only works with the `BiConsumer` support. Besides that, non-capturing lambda expression are slightly more efficient.

---

Now that you added the idea of supporting multiple parameters, it’s not that simple or concise anymore. Generally, this idea would work with capturing lambdas, e.g.

```
public void handle(Context ctx) {
    Validator.on(ctx).param("instanceId").ifValid( param ->
    Validator.on(ctx).param("anotherParam").ifValid( param2 ->
    Validator.on(ctx).param("yetOneMore").ifValid( param3 -> {
        ... business logic on param, param2, param3
    })));
}
```

This could be improved by providing the validator, preconfigured with the context, as a parameter to the `BiConsumer`:

```
public void handle(Context ctx) {
    Validator.on(ctx).param("instanceId").ifValid( (v,param) ->
        v.param("anotherParam").ifValid( (v,param2) ->
        v.param("yetOneMore").ifValid( (v,param3) -> {
        ... business logic on param, param2, param3
    })));
}
```

you may decide yourself whether this is a feasible solution…

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking right until we got to multiple params

Comment: But this `nested` lambdas will 1) make things unreadable with e.g. >3 params and 2) more important, if I need to end business method early, I can not use `return` - which is too much just for the sake of validation.

Comment: Of course, you can use `return` inside a lambda expression. And in the case that the validation fails, the action won’t get called at all. I know that nested lambda expressions are not the best thing, that’s why I already said that multiple parameters won’t work so well. You could add other functional interfaces for consuming *n* args, to ease the pain, but you can’t cover arbitrary numbers of parameters so at one point, you’ll have to resort to nested lambdas again…

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have all the names of your params in a `Stream<String>`, you could try something like this:

```
public void handle(Context ctx) {
    Stream<String> names = Stream.of("name1", "name2", "name3"); // just an example

    if (names.map(Context::getParam).allMatch(Validation::validate)) {
        // business logic here
    } else {
        ctx.markError().end();
    }
}
```

Or, to follow the same flow style as you:

```
if (!names.map(Context::getParam).allMatch(Validation::validate)) {
    ctx.markError().end();
    return;
}
// business logic here
```

Comment: Nice - except I need each param value in business logic, right? So I would need to fetch the value again from the `context` (although I am sure now it is valid).

Comment: @игор You could cache it `Context.getParam` method, so that you don't fetch it again. Or you could also use the [*memoization* technique](https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-automatic-memoization).

Comment: Yeah, but its not the caching here - it's the _repetition_ of the fetching. I mean, imagine developers need to write twice the param name - they will make a mistake soon :)